# Would this be generating a transcendental number?

Tags: transcendental-numbers

Based on my understanding, a [transcendental](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_number) number is a number that is not [computable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_number), or cannot be generated by an algorithm. Let's say that (theoretically) I randomly generate a number that is infinitely long with dice. Since it is extremely unlikely that a computer algorithm would be able to generate that number, then I could conclude that I generated a transcendental number with a specific set of steps (which is the definition of an algorithm).

Obviously, there's something wrong since transcendental numbers should not be able to be generated through an algorithm. What's flawed about the logic presented above? Or is my understanding of transcendental numbers, computable numbers, or algorithms wrong?

Comment: Your understanding is wrong, since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty10^{-n!}$ is transcendental.

Comment: Well known trascendentals are $e$ and $\pi$, they certainly can be very well approximated by simple algorithms (Maclaurin series for $e^1$, Wallis product for $\pi$). They obviously can't be computed exactly, but neither can e.g. $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Correct is however : Every non-computable number is transcendental. Since if it were algebraic irrational or even rational, it would be computable.